# I get a "baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it” message when baking textures

Tags: texture-baking

For some reason, when trying to bake a texture, I sometimes only get that message (on the bottom) and the image editor only shows a blank/black image. Sometimes it works, sometimes not, no idea why. The mesh is a simple deformed plane. All I'm trying to do is to have the texure (made procedurally) as an image file, so I can add it to a displace modifier. Not sure what else should I include in this description.
Here's the .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XIVXZJZnasZ9okJYllfRBpfjvg0QsjA/view?usp=sharing

[image: deformed plane]

[image: shader editor]

Comment: Your 50k verts plane has a Subdivision Surface modifier with 3 & 5(!) levels. In the viewport, this bumps the vert count to 600k, in render mode it's a few million.  Do you really need this? You can't bake Metallic (and Subsurface Scattering). Set it to 0 for the bake and reset it for the final setup.

Comment: The warning message in the title is a reminder that you must save or pack the baked image. Else it's lost when you quit Blender.

Comment: Mr. Blunder, I deleted the subdiv surface modifier, but I still only got the message, without the image actually showing up in the image editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bake the image you just need to set *Metallic* of the *Principled BSDF* node to `0.000`. If you don't do this the image will be black. *Subsurface* must be `0.000`, too. (just saying). After you have baked the image restore the *Metallic* value.

[image: baked image]

The warning message *"Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it”* is a reminder that you need to save the baked image to a file (=external data) or pack it (=embed it into the blend file) after the baking process.

If you choose *File* you need to save the image explicitly <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> every time you change it (bake, paint, etc). It's ***not*** saved with the blend file!

Select *Image > Save* **or** *Image > Pack* in the *Image Editor*:

[image: save image]

Sometimes there is an update glitch. If the image doesn't look like it should, try *Image > Reload* to reload it from disk just to be sure you see what you get. And after you saved it the first time, of course ;-) else it's discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your time dude, this helped.