# When I bake my model, why does almost all the texture come out black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I was preparing everything to bake the video and I mean the color of the mesh and when I did the whole texture came out black but the part of the head did not. I was checking everything and everything was well set up

So you can help me better here I leave the link of the project and if possible respond with images for more context

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oDUukYLxvnBmr7qFtntLcMv0cndrxL9A/view?usp=drive_link

do the baking in diffusion because I leave it in normal (I know my UV is horrendous)[image: enter image descripción here]

Comment: Bienvenido, inglés es obligatorio para el sitio, puedes usar el traductor de google si así lo deseas.... (translation) Hello and welcome, English is mandatory for the site, If you want to, you could use Google translate

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: Your robot is metallic, so you have set set *Metallic* settings of the *Principled BSDF*. That's ok. But you cannot bake a metal color image. It looks like you want to create a texture atlas (all robot parts in one image). Since there are non-metallic parts you can bake a metallic mask (grey values, black=0=no metal, white=1=metal). To do so, use an *Emission* node and Bake Type *Emit* for this. To bake the color, set *Metallic* to 0. Then you can bake the output of the *Principled BSDF* node. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/233318/107598

Comment: Or have a look here (but there are no images, sorry): https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251964/107598

Comment: Thank you I had already forgotten. that was the problem today I just have to learn how to make better UV